# Genesis / custom template page / setting the page title and meta desc

Tags: php, seo, genesis-theme-framework, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

My WP site is running Genesis. I've just implemented my first custom page template in a child theme. The template runs some PHP and makes some data available to any page based on the template using shortcodes. All is working well, except...

For SEO, I'd like to set several items in the *head* section - most importantly the page title but also some meta items. I use the Yoast Wordpress SEO and this section is top/tailed with a Yoast comment so perhaps it's taken charge of these fields.

Are there any filters I can use (perhaps with a higher priority than Yoast uses) to set selected *head* items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoast Support kindly provided me with the following reference:

https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/

Using the following filters calling my own functions, I was able to change everything in the header based on dynamic content.

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'setPageTitle', 10);
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc', 'setMetaDesc', 10);
add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'setCanonical', 10);
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image', 'setOG_Image', 10);
add_filter('the_title', 'setTitle', 10);
```